# C++ Tensorflow lite, undefined reference on some functions

Tags: c++, tensorflow, cmake, makefile, tensorflow-lite

I'm trying to build and run a project using tensorflow lite on my debian 11 intel x86_64 architecture. So far I've followed the official [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/build_cmake#create_a_cmake_project_which_uses_tensorflow_lite) and the official [github example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/lite/examples/minimal).

Here are the steps I've followed:

1. On ~/Desktop/ I ran `git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow.git tensorflow_src`
2. `mkdir tflite_build` & `cd ~/Desktop/tflite_build`
3. `cmake ../tensorflow_src/tensorflow/lite`
4. `cmake --build .` I've removed the `-J` flag regardless of what the docs says because it causes my pc to freeze.
5. `mkdir ~/Desktop/tf_test` & `cd ~/Desktop/tf_test`
6. Create a CMakeLists.txt and a main.cpp file inside `tf_test`directory.
7. Put the main code from the minimal example on the github repo provided above then this code in CMake:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(minimal C CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -DTFLITE_DISABLE_TELEMETRY=1")

set(TENSORFLOW_SOURCE_DIR "" CACHE PATH
  "Directory that contains the TensorFlow project" )
if(NOT TENSORFLOW_SOURCE_DIR)
  get_filename_component(TENSORFLOW_SOURCE_DIR
    "/home/user/Desktop/tensorflow_src" ABSOLUTE)
endif()

add_subdirectory(
  "${TENSORFLOW_SOURCE_DIR}/tensorflow/lite"
  "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/tensorflow-lite" EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)

add_executable(minimal minimal.cc)
target_link_libraries(minimal tensorflow-lite)
```

8. Created the folder `tf_Test/build` and ran `cmake ..` inside it.
9. After cmake is completed I run `make` inside the build directory and I'm getting the following error:

```
...
[100%] Linking CXX executable minimal
/usr/bin/ld: tensorflow-lite/libtensorflow-lite.a(interpreter.cc.o): in function `tflite::impl::Interpreter::ReportTelemetrySettings(char const*)':
interpreter.cc:(.text+0x292f): undefined reference to `tflite::telemetry::TelemetryReportSettings(TfLiteContext*, char const*, TfLiteTelemetryInterpreterSettings const*)'
/usr/bin/ld: tensorflow-lite/libtensorflow-lite.a(subgraph.cc.o): in function `tflite::Subgraph::Invoke()':
subgraph.cc:(.text+0x41c0): undefined reference to `tflite::telemetry::TelemetryReportEvent(TfLiteContext*, char const*, TfLiteStatus)'
/usr/bin/ld: tensorflow-lite/libtensorflow-lite.a(subgraph.cc.o): in function `tflite::Subgraph::ModifyGraphWithDelegate(TfLiteDelegate*)':
subgraph.cc:(.text+0x6ad0): undefined reference to `tflite::telemetry::TelemetryReportEvent(TfLiteContext*, char const*, TfLiteStatus)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/minimal.dir/build.make:184: minimal] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1408: CMakeFiles/minimal.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:149: all] Error 2
```

Notice that it's not saying this for all the functions. For example this works   `std::unique_ptr<tflite::FlatBufferModel> model = tflite::FlatBufferModel::BuildFromFile(filename);` without errors.

These tree are causing trouble:     `tflite::ops::builtin::BuiltinOpResolver resolver; std::unique_ptr<tflite::Interpreter> interpreter; tflite::InterpreterBuilder(*model, resolver)(&interpreter);`

Note: I've trimmed some code compare to the github example for the sake of testing it, so only the above 4 lines are present on my main.

Why am I getting this error? I've tried compiling with bazel aswell but I'm getting the same error. What am I missing?

Comment: If you notice, they moved to CMake/Bazel some time ago and they are most likely fixing these issues as they go. I would recommend going to their official github and *submit an issue*. As a side note there is no `TFLITE_DISABLE_TELEMETRY` as far as I am aware of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably it is missing from the CMakeLists file

Update [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/082c562ec7a6a33da2a6b60c191474b5ae6b73e2/tensorflow/lite/CMakeLists.txt) and add
tensorflow/lite/profiling/telemetry/telemetry.cc and
tensorflow/lite/profiling/telemetry/telemetry.h
to [TFLITE_PROFILER_SRCS](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/082c562ec7a6a33da2a6b60c191474b5ae6b73e2/tensorflow/lite/CMakeLists.txt#L491)

It is also worth creating issue on Tensorflow repo for the team

Comment: That did work, thanks. I've opened an issue detailing the problem.

Comment: Can i have a link to the issue with tflite. this is blocking me as well...