# Tensorflow android cmake build can't find python

Tags: android, c++, linux, tensorflow, cmake

I'm trying to build tflite in my android project using cmake. I've managed to work this approach on the linux (debian) version of the same project.When compiling the arm64 version I followed the [official docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/build_cmake_arm) When I open android studio and press build/run on top right corner, I get this error:

```
In file included from /home/user/Desktop/official_stuff/tensorflow_src/tensorflow/lite/python/interpreter_wrapper/numpy.cc:17:
In file included from /home/user/Desktop/official_stuff/tensorflow_src/tensorflow/lite/python/interpreter_wrapper/numpy.h:49:
In file included from /usr/include/python3.9/Python.h:8:
/usr/include/python3.9/pyconfig.h:9:12: fatal error: 'aarch64-linux-gnu/python3.9/pyconfig.h' file not found
```

When I open the file that throws the error I see the this line indicating that it's searching for it in the system:

`#include <aarch64-linux-gnu/python3.9/pyconfig.h>`

I ran `sudo find / -name "aarch64-linux-gnu"` to see whether I have that file or not and indeed I have this file installed:

```
user@debian:~$ sudo find / -name "aarch64-linux-gnu"
...
/home/user/toolchains/gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-aarch64-linux-gnu/aarch64-linux-gnu/include/c++/8.3.0/aarch64-linux-gnu
find: ‘/run/user/1000/doc’: Permission denied
find: ‘/run/user/1000/gvfs’: Permission denied
/usr/lib/mesa-diverted/aarch64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu
/usr/share/gdb/auto-load/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu
/usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu
/usr/include/finclude/aarch64-linux-gnu
/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu
```

I located inside `/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu` and indeed saw `/python3.9/pyconfig.h`.

The way I did everything is this:

1. `sudo git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow.git /home/user/Desktop/official_stuff/tensorflow_src`
2. `curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/mirror.tensorflow.org/developer.arm.com/media/Files/downloads/gnu-a/8.3-2019.03/binrel/gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-aarch64-linux-gnu.tar.xz`
3. `mkdir -p ${HOME}/toolchains`
4. `tar xvf gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-aarch64-linux-gnu.tar.xz -C ${HOME}/toolchains`
5. 

```
ARMCC_PREFIX=${HOME}/toolchains/gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-
ARMCC_FLAGS="-funsafe-math-optimizations"
cmake -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=${ARMCC_PREFIX}gcc \
  -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=${ARMCC_PREFIX}g++ \
  -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS="${ARMCC_FLAGS}" \
  -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="${ARMCC_FLAGS}" \
  -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE:BOOL=ON \
  -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=Linux \
  -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR=aarch64 \
  ../tensorflow/lite/
```

6. And then I needed to ran `dpkg --add-architecture arm64`, `apt-get update`, `sudo apt install libpython3-dev:arm64`
7. I simply clicked build ran after connecting my android device. It compiled for a while and then throw the error.

Here is the cmake snippet I ran that contains my tflite inclusion:

```
set(TENSORFLOW_SOURCE_DIR "" CACHE PATH
  "Directory that contains the TensorFlow project" )
if(NOT TENSORFLOW_SOURCE_DIR)
  get_filename_component(TENSORFLOW_SOURCE_DIR
    "/home/user/Desktop/official_stuff/tensorflow_src" ABSOLUTE)
endif()
add_library(tensorflowlite SHARED IMPORTED)
add_subdirectory(
  "/home/user/Desktop/official_stuff/tensorflow_src/tensorflow/lite"
  "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/tensorflow-lite" EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL
)
...
target_link_libraries(
        my_proj

        tensorflow-lite
)
```

How can I fix this issue?

Note: I got to this point following a series of questions which all resolved:

1. [An undefined error.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75245826/c-tensorflow-lite-undefined-reference-on-some-functions)
2. [Question regarding android build.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75323248/will-cmake-compiled-tflite-work-on-android)

More details about how I built everything can be found here. I'm on debian 11.

Comment: Because in the last questions you didn't follow my suggestions carefully and did extra (uncalled for) steps, I highly recommend that you post both the **entire** output log (or at least the last 200 lines or so) and ideally the entire **CMakeLists.txt** that you use to build this. It will help anyone who wishes to tackle this issue.

Comment: @MilanŠ. If you are talking about the android build output, this is the entire log. The entire cmake is a bit long due to my project having a lot of dependencies, this is the only part I added.

Comment: Also did you modify the `Python.h` file? Because the one I opened has `#include "pyconfig.h"` did you by any chance edit the file? EDIT: You can even [check it here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Include/Python.h)

Comment: @MilanŠ. No, I did not touch any file that does not belong to me

Comment: did you try and remove this `-I/usr/include/python3.9 -I/usr/include/python3.9`? And `sudo apt install python3:arm64` To see what happens? EDIT: This is btw what I meant by the unwanted steps, it's really hard to debug something when you copy paste random solutions and pray that they work. Take a look at this path `/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu` vs `/usr/include/python3.9` you are probably (again) mixing architectures.

Comment: I've removed those flags from cmake, ran `sudo apt install python3:arm64` (which weirdly deleted gnome-desktop, turning my pc into a terminal until I re-installed it), ran android studio build again, got the previous error: `In file included from /home/user/Desktop/official_stuff/tensorflow_src/tensorflow/lite/python/interpreter_wrapper/numpy.cc:17:
/home/user/Desktop/official_stuff/tensorflow_src/tensorflow/lite/python/interpreter_wrapper/numpy.h:49:10: fatal error: 'Python.h' file not found`. Both /usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu & /usr/include/python3.9 are present.

Comment: Perhaps a side question but, did you or did you not follow the official cross-compilation guide [from "Android developer"](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cmake#command-line)? They specify a lot more defines than you do and use "android-ndk". To me it seems you will keep running into issues. However most of these issues here could be fixed by changing the tensorflow `CMakeLists.txt`. And target including the correct header locations for individual targets. But this is too time heavy for me. So I will let other people (or preferably you) tackle it.

Comment: My only advise is - use CMake instructions and not compile flags. Because you can very easily **bork up** different things in the build itself.

Comment: @MilanŠ. I did not follow that link, I've followed https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/build_cmake_arm . Alright, I'll try not to set flags as much as possible.

Comment: I'm talking about what you did with `CXX_COMPILER_FLAGS` the `-D` defines are fine.

Comment: @MilanŠ. yes, on the previous question I added those flags, now I've removed them. Unfortunately I had to re install debian because trying to install `sudo apt install python3:arm64` caused some really weird behaviours (My system was acting weird beforehand anyways). I'll try the steps you said, clean and keep you updated. Thanks in advance.